# call to a member function move() on null (Rest api laravel)

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, react-native

I'm developing app in react native using expo and back-end is in Laravel 
Basically I'm doing Profile module to upload photo

Back-end Api is developed 
Here is my back-end code

```
public function EditProfile(Request $request){


            //Creating model and input values
        $profile = new ProfilePicEditModel;
        $profile->user_id = Auth::id();
        $profile->name    = $request->name;
        $profile->occupation    = $request->occupation;
        $profile->waystatus    = $request->waystatus;

        //Image Proceesing to Upload

         $fileName=Auth::id().".png";
            $path = $request->file('image')->move(public_path("/ShareYourMealProfilePics"),$fileName);
            $photoURL= url('/ShareYourMealProfilePics/'.$fileName);

        $profile->image=$photoURL;
        $profile->phone = $request->phone;
        $profile->save();
        return response()->json($profile,200);



    }
```

Here is my model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ProfilePicEditModel extends Model
{

    protected $table="profile";
    //public $timestamps=false;


    protected $fillable=[
        'user_id',
        'name',
        'occupation',
        'waystatus',
        'image',
        'phone',
    ];
}
```

And the code of React native is here

```
export default class EditProfile extends React.Component{
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          name:'',
          occupation:'',
          waystatus:'',
          image:'',
          phone:'',
        };
      }



    selectPicture = async () => {
        await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
        const { cancelled, uri } = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
          aspect: 1,
          allowsEditing: true,
        });
        if (!cancelled) this.setState({ image: uri });
      };

      updateProfile=async()=>{
         // console.log(this.state.name,this.state.occupation,this.state.waystatus,this.state.image,this.state.phone);

        fetch('http://192.168.1.7:8000/api/EditProfile',{
            method:'post',
            headers:{
              'Authorization': `Bearer ${GLOBAL.mytoken}`,
              'Content-Type':'application/json',
             'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({


                "name":this.state.name,
                "occupation":this.state.occupation,
                "waystatus":this.state.waystatus,
                "image":this.state.image,
                "phone":this.state.phone




            })
          }).then((response)=> response.json())
          .then((res)=>{
            if(typeof(res.message)!="undefined"){
              Alert.alert(res.message);
            }
            else{
                Alert.alert("Success","You have succesfuly Updated Your Profile",
                [
              {
                text: 'Continue', onPress: () => {
                   Actions.Profile();
                }
              }
            ],
            { cancelable: false })
            }
          }).catch((error)=>{
            console.error(error);
          });
      }


    render(){
        const {goBack} = this.props.navigation;
        return(
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true} style={{marginHorizontal:10}}>
                <View style={styles.titleBar}>
                    <Ionicons name="ios-arrow-back" size={24} color="#52575D"
                    onPress={() => goBack()}
                    ></Ionicons>
                    <Text style={{fontSize: 22,fontWeight:"400",justifyContent:"center",marginLeft:110}}>Edit Profile </Text>

            </View>

            <Text style={{marginLeft:30,fontSize:17,marginTop:25,fontWeight:"300"}}>Please Select Your Profile Pic</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={this.selectPicture}>
            <FontAwesome name="camera" size={35} style={{justifyContent:"center",marginTop:17,alignSelf:"center"}}/>

            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Item floatingLabel style={{marginTop:10}}>
              <Label style={{marginLeft:30}}>Name </Label>
              <Input  style={{marginLeft:10,marginRight:10}}
                  onChangeText={(name) => this.setState({name})}
              />
            </Item>
            <Item floatingLabel style={{marginTop:20}}>
              <Label style={{marginLeft:30}}>Sub Name/Occupation </Label>
              <Input style={{marginLeft:10,marginRight:10}} 
                  onChangeText={(occupation) => this.setState({occupation})}
              />
            </Item>
            <Item floatingLabel style={{marginTop:20}}>
              <Label style={{marginLeft:30}}>Status </Label>
              <Input style={{marginLeft:10,marginRight:10}} 
                  onChangeText={(waystatus) => this.setState({waystatus})}
              />
            </Item>
            <Item floatingLabel style={{marginTop:20}}>
              <Label style={{marginLeft:30}}>Phone No.</Label>
              <Input style={{marginLeft:10,marginRight:10}} keyboardType={'numeric'} returnKeyType='done'
              onChangeText={(phone) => this.setState({phone})}
               />
            </Item>


            <Button rounded style={styles.postSeat}
            onPress={()=>this.updateProfile()}>
                        <Text>Update</Text>
                        </Button>
            </ScrollView>
            </SafeAreaView>

        )}
}
```

When i select the image and fill all the fields and then click update button its

error 
**call to a member function move() on null**

I dont know where is the error 
But i think error because of image upload on backend 
please let me know error is in backend or in the react native side

And one more Question
We only store the "uri" of image????

Comment: Looks like the file was not uploded. I don't know about react, but in laravel you can avoid the exception with validation or with a conditional `if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
    // move the file and save the url
}`

Comment: > And one more Question We only store the "uri" of image? . I use to save in DB only the filename and the path in a config file, so if i move the files to other path i can easily change the path for all files

Comment: if i try on post man it works fine the url of image is uploaded on DB and image in public folder but when using react native then it error come

Comment: Well, then the issue is on the react code. Someone else with react knowledge can help you with that. Try adding react and javascript tags to the question to reach more people

Answer (score 0):

The issue is from the front end. You can't upload the image using basic JSON Stringify. You have to build the body of the request with **Formdata**.

The *FormData* interface provides a way to easily construct a set of key/value pairs representing form fields and their values, which can then be easily sent as the body of a request. It uses the same format a form would use if the encoding type were set to "multipart/form-data".

Update your **updateProfile** function as follows and it should work fine:

```
updateProfile = async() = > {
    // console.log(this.state.name,this.state.occupation,this.state.waystatus,this.state.image,this.state.phone);

    const formdata = new FormData();

    formdata.append('name', this.state.name);
    formdata.append('occupation', this.state.occupation);
    formdata.append('waystatus', this.state.waystatus);
    formdata.append('phone', this.state.phone);
    formdata.append('image', {
        uri: this.state.image,
        type: "image/jpeg",
        name: `${Date.now()}` //random name for the image
    });


    fetch('http://192.168.1.7:8000/api/EditProfile', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${GLOBAL.mytoken}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        body: formdata
    }).then((response) = > response.json())
        .then((res) = > {
            if (typeof(res.message) != "undefined") {
                Alert.alert(res.message);
            } else {
                Alert.alert("Success", "You have succesfuly Updated Your Profile", [{
                    text: 'Continue',
                    onPress: () = > {
                        Actions.Profile();
                    }
                }], {
                    cancelable: false
                })
            }
        }).
    catch ((error) = > {
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```